# Update method in Rest like controllers

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data

I want to write rest like method for entity update. In this case I retrieve entity id from url and data from request body. The issue is in binding id with bean. Because neither EntityManager nor Spring-Data Crud Repo haven't `update(id, bean)` method. So I can set it myself

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        user.setId(id);   //Very bad
        return "usersEdit";
    }
    user.setId(id);  //Bad
    repository.save(user);
    return "redirect:/users/" + id;
}
```

or dismiss DRY and put id in forms as private field to.
 Is there are any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

In Spring 3.1 a @ModelAttribute will be instantiated from a path variable if the path variable and the model attribute names are the same and there is a converter to instantiate the model attribute from the path variable value:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{account}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String update(@Valid @ModelAttribute Account account, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "accounts/edit";
    }
    this.accountManager.saveOrUpdate(account);
    return "redirect:../accounts";
}
```

The full example is available at:
https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-31-demo